# Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#

Estou a desenvolver um aplicativo de Registro acadêmico em C#.
Tenho algumas compositores de Objetos como:

```
public class Turma
{
    public String Descricao { get; set; }
    public int QtdAlunos { get; set; }
    public Turno turno { get; set; }
    public Curso curso { get; set; }
    public Semestre semestre { get; set; }
    public Nivel nivel { get; set; }
    public int Ano { get; set; }
    public String Sala { get; set; }
}
```

A dificuldade e a seguinte, tenho um `procedure` de pesquisa no `SqlServer` que recebe parâmetros do tipo `int` dos objetos: `Turno`, `Curso`, `Semestre` e `Nivel`.
Populei as `comboBox` com os seus respectivos objetos como segue o exemplo:

```
public static void Nivel()
{
    NivelController nivelController = new NivelController();
    NivelColecao nivelColecao = nivelController.NivelConsultar();

    cboNivel.DataSource = null;
    cboNivel.DataSource = nivelColecao;

    cboNivel.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
    cboNivel.ValueMember = "IDNivel";

    cboNivel.Update();
    cboNivel.Refresh();
}
```

Então.. o que deve acontecer é que no `selectedIndex` da `ComboBox` deve atualizar a `DataGridView`.

```
private void cboNivel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        turma.nivel = new Nivel();
        turma.nivel.IDNivel = (int)cboNivel.SelectedValue;
}
```

O erro é o seguinte:

> SpecifiedCast is not valid e Unable to cast object of type
>   'Model.Nivel' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

```
publi  void Turma(Turma turma) 
{
    try
    {
        TurmaController turmaController = new TurmaController();
        TurmaColecao turmaColecao = turmaController.TurmaConsultar(turma);

        var TurmaListar = turmaColecao.Select(Turma => new
        {
            Turma = Turma.Descricao,
            QtdAlunos = Turma.QtdAlunos,
            Sala = Turma.Sala,
            Ano = Turma.Ano,
            Curso = Turma.curso.Descricao,
            Turno = Turma.turno.Descricao,
            Nivel = Turma.nivel.Descricao,
            Semestre = Turma.semestre.Descricao

        }).ToList();

        dGV.DataSource = null;
        dGV.DataSource = TurmaListar;

        dGV.AutoResizeColumns();

        dGV.Update();
        dGV.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao fazer a consulta. Detalhes: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: No seu último código está "publi".

Comment: foi uma falha ao copiar o codigo para aqui, mas nao e isso que esta a infkuenciar o erro